# Maven compilation Failure on EMF-Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, emf

I have to work with an EMF-Project and need to use some of the classes in another package.
When I try to build the generated code with maven I get this Failure:

```
[INFO] 6 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.844 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-31T16:25:42+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/163M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project datamodel: Compilation failure:
 Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/.../util/ModelSwitch.java:[20,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Switch
[ERROR] location: package org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util
[ERROR] /C:/.../util/ModelSwitch.java:[85,38] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Switch
[ERROR] /C:/.../util/ModelSwitch.java:[114,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /C:/.../util/ModelSwitch.java:[126,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /C:/.../util/ModelSwitch.java:[1341,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /C:/.../util/ModelAdapterFactory.java:[365,35] method doSwitch in class com...util.ModelSwitch<T1> cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR] required: int,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
[ERROR] found: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
[ERROR] reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

All libraries are imported and in the pom, yet it still got problems with the generated ModelSwitch class.

This Error and the fact, that Eclipse Luna is buggy as hell are driving me crazy! Could somebody please help me and explain how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml file, or at least the relevant bits please?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the `Switch` classes were changed in some recent version of EMF. Are you sure that the version in your `pom.xml` matches the version used to generate those files in Eclipse?

Comment: @tobias_k could you post a link to a reference of this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [different version in the repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.emf). It seems like EMF renamed their artifacts some time ago. Instead of this (analogously for your other EMF dependencies):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecore</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1.v20100914-1218</version>
</dependency>
```

try to use this form (note the different `artifactId`):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0-v20150123-0347</version>
</dependency>
```

Here, much newer versions are available. For me, every version from `2.8` upwards seems to work. You could also use a range, to always get the latest version:

```
<version>[2.8.0,2.99.99]</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the latest versions of the components you have as far as I can tell

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecore</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0-v200706262000</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0-v200706262000</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0-v20150123-0347</version>
</dependency>
```